# Book about an orphan who has to bring back an antidote from a dumpster-prison and can copy any voice

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for a book I read around ten years ago (but is probably older), but I can't remember the name.

It's in the future. A boy is born very ugly, and spends his childhood in an orphanage. But at some point the orphanage becomes very dangerous, so he has to escape by hiding with the dead bodies.

He is very gifted (learning languages and copying accents) and he survives by selling clothes in the street. One day, the government sends him (I can't remember why him in particular) to a new model of prison: people are sentenced for life in gigantic "dumpsters" where they survive by recycling what the people throw on them by air. He is asked to bring back an antidote for a disease developed in a lab by terrorists that live in this "dump-prison".

In the end, he comes back contaminated with a disease and proceeds to transmit it to as many people from the town as possible; to do so, I remember, he has sex with a prostitute. He also transmits it to the leader of this town, the one that had asked him to recover the antidote.

MORE DETAILS:
I remember that at some point the character has sex with a girl, so it must be for an adult audience. This girl was part of the rich part of town and had run away.
In the "dumpster-prison", he gets acid on his face while recycling and he discovers that his scar is a factor of beauty  in this place and women find him virile/attractive.
The cover of the French version (maybe you have a different one) shows a boy who is running away from a flying machine in a dump.
At first, I think the orphanage was Catholic, and the hero often accompanied priests in town because he had learned the local slang very fast.

Comment: At the start I thought this was going to be *Ender's Shadow*, but it went in a really different direction. :)

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SciFi.SE! You've got quite a lot of details here, which is good. Could you also take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit] in any more information you can remember?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When was "a long time ago?"  Do you remember what the cover of the book looked like at all?

Comment: Do you happen to remember what French phrase was used for the "dumpster prison"?